# Click and stay in same position when some element above hide

Tags: jquery, click, position, expand

[image]

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/My29d/

I have content like this #1, #2, #3, #4 and more...

When I click `readmore` #2 and click `readmore` #1, it's ok because hidden content expand below and window stay in same position.

But when I click `readmore` #1 and scoll to content #2 so click on `readmore` #2

expanded content #1 will hide and content #2 will show full content.

So window position doesn't stay in same position right ?

I have no idea how to do.

*Maybe use scroll to current expanded element ?*

```
more_btn.on('click', function () {
    more_btn.show();
    more_content.hide();
    $(this).hide().next('div').show().css('display', 'inline');
});
```

PS : If this question is bad unstanding, I'm sorry and tell me to expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm done now :

```
var more_btn = $('div > span');
var more_content = $('div > div');

more_btn.on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var top = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop();
    more_btn.show();
    more_content.hide();
    $(this).hide().next('div').show().css('display', 'inline');
    $('html, body').scrollTop(
        $this.next('div').offset().top - top
    );

});
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/My29d/4/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if i understand what you exactly want, but if i understand correctly then this might what you are looking for:

```
var more_btn = $('div > span');
var more_content = $('div > div');

more_btn.on('click', function () {
    more_btn.show();
    more_content.hide();
    $(this).hide().next('div').show().css('display', 'inline');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).parent('div').offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/My29d/1/

Comment: Thanks , this is a googe scrolling, I did it too. But can all element stay in same position like before clicked ? (like http://jsfiddle.net/My29d/2/ , but readmore content will hide it too)

Comment: what do you mean by same position before clicked ? you can capture the `scrollTop` value and after you do the animation scroll back to the same value

Comment: If we cant do this , so I will use your current answer :D

Comment: What about using  e.pageY, $(this).offset().top;